# How to combine 2 bash commands with print0 included

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Bash version: 3.5

I have 2 favorite commands, that i use a lot

here's my code

1. `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum -b`
2. `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c "%y"`

How to combine them and get result similar to my expectation below.

Result:

`4d452a2b17f0a6ea9408f959ad7a28a35d67c810 2016-06-28 16:09:34.000000000 211 ./DEW-FILES_COPY_2016-06-28_16092425_.bat`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This way:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'file={};m5s=$(md5sum -b  $file|cut -d" " -f1);echo "$m5s "$(stat -c "%y" $file)" $file"' \;
```